# UNIX asking for user input "y" or "n"

Tags: unix, syntax, input

What I want to do is give the user an option to delete the file by typing "y" or "n"

However I keep getting the error:

> line 38: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
>   line 38:               v)    $verbose = true ;

( I have a variable named verbose and it's equal to false )

My code is as follows:

```
while getopts :iv opt
do
     case $opt in
          i) read -p "remove ? " opt
            case $opt in
              y|Y)
              $interactive = true
                echo "YOU HAVE DELETED THIS FILE"
              sendToBin ;;
              n|N)
                echo "YOU HAVE CHOSEN NOT TO DELETE THIS FILE"
                exit ;;
             esac
           v)   $verbose = true
                echo "YOU HAVE CHOSEN VERBOSE" ;;
           \?)echo "WHAT ARE YOU CRAZY"
                exit  ;;
      esac
 done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Setting variables is done like this:

```
var=1
```

not like this:

```
$var = 1
```

Comment: The `$` is how they are accessed.